# How to get parameter of ng2-file-upload with endback?

Tags: php, angular, ionic-framework

I want to get parameter with php. I try with my code but it still not work save into folder (parameter) this is post http image:

[image: post http image]

Ionic framework

```
  this.uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = (item: any) => {
        this..uploader.options.additionalParameter = {
        folder : this.herb_id <---- my parameter folder name
      };
```

endback(php)

```
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description,X-Requested-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {

   /------------- folder name --------------------------//
   $path = 'uploads/';
   $path .=$_FILES['options']['additionalParameter']['folder']; <---- folder name
   $path .= '/';

  $originalName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
  $ext = '.'.pathinfo($originalName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $generatedName = md5($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']).$ext;
  //$filePath = $path.$generatedName;
  $filePath = $path.$generatedName;

  if (!is_writable($path)) {
    echo json_encode(array(
      'status' => false,
      'msg'    => 'Destination directory not writable.'
    ));
    exit;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i can solve it as this code

for ionic

```
 this.fileField.uploader.onBuildItemForm = (fileItem, form) => {
      form.append('folder', String(this.herb_id));
      return { fileItem, form };
    };
```

for php

```
 /------------- folder name --------------------------//
   $path = 'uploads/';
   $path .=$_POST['folder']; <---- folder name
   $path .= '/';
```